# Do I need to reinstall MySQL to use node js sql database?

Tags: mysql, vps

I'm making a database in mysql on my windows machine, I'll export it as my_data.sql, and I'd like to put it on my node js project then upload it all in my vps machine, do I need reinstall my sql in this new SO or does the .sql file already contain all user permissions and info in order to set up it all fine in node?

Comment: You should not have exported user permissions and configurations (mysql database) and yes, you need to install and configure a new mysql database on your VPS.

Comment: is there any way to embed all of it to my node js project?

Comment: You can distribute the mysql installer with your node.js application (requires a commercial licence, though), or you can use a dockerized version of mysql, but in either case, there are certain configuration that the user need to enter.

Comment: I'm using sql lite, I think it solved my problem

Comment: sqlite is not suitable for web applications. It's a file-based, small-footprint, embedded database.